# compare with pictures in database through face features SQL serve

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

We want to compare with pictures in database through face features to can recognize the faces through live camera

For example:
I have program, and admin has permissions to insert employees pictures(on SQL server) and when employee1 passes in front of the camera, The camera detect the face and take a picture of employee1 face and compare it with another employees and print the employee1 name in label

our problem is how can we compare employee1 face with another employees in database through face features
we are using OpenCV, EmguCV, SQL server and c#

Comment: Your question is too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Thats a requirement, do you have an actual problem?

Comment: @Kmeixner Thanks i add an example of my problem

Comment: @RonBeyer Yeah i have an actual problem